# Flutter How to navigate from page to page without any users Interaction

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm writing a flutter application and i want to change the page without any users interaction , i wrote a timer methode and i want to change the page when the timer is 0
           Timer _timer;
        int _start = 5;

```
    void startTimer() {
   const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  _timer = new Timer.periodic(
  oneSec,
  (Timer timer) => setState(
    () {
      if (_start < 1) {
        timer.cancel();
      } else {
        _start = _start - 1;
      }
    },
  ),
);
   }
   @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
         startTimer();
     }
```

the timer wille be from 5 to 0 i want to change the page when start wil be 0 And thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a better approach to go with Visibility widget rather route.
You can replace your any widget with the Text widget in demo.
**check out demo code below:**

```
// main.dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CountDownDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class CountDownDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CountDownDemoState createState() => _CountDownDemoState();
}

class _CountDownDemoState extends State<CountDownDemo> {
  int _start = 5;

  void startTimer() {
    const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(
        () {
          if (_start < 1) {
            timer.cancel();
          } else {
            _start = _start - 1;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    startTimer();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Countdown Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Visibility(
              child: Text("Text 5"),
              visible: _start == 5 ? true : false,
            ),
            Visibility(
              child: Text("Text 4"),
              visible: _start == 4 ? true : false,
            ),
            Visibility(
              child: Text("Text 3"),
              visible: _start == 3 ? true : false,
            ),
            Visibility(
              child: Text("Text 2"),
              visible: _start == 2 ? true : false,
            ),
            Visibility(
              child: Text("Text 1"),
              visible: _start == 1 ? true : false,
            ),
            Visibility(
              child: Text("Timer is complete"),
              visible: _start == 0 ? true : false,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Output:**
[image: output of demo with visibility widget and timer]

Comment: thankyou but how can i write the code of Navigator.push

Comment: just replace your pages where Text widgets are implemented. With the timer, They will automatically be called and you don't need to use navigator for that.

Comment: If you found your answer, kindly accept and upvote. thanks.

Comment: Have you faced any issue or else?

Comment: it represents can you please give me in exemple in wich you navigate to another page

Comment: i'm sorry yes it works correctly as i want it thank you very very very much <3

Comment: ok done i have another question if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61365246/flutter-the-application-crashed-when-i-change-the-screen

Comment: Sure. It seems you are new on the stack overflow. I want to let you know that you can press on the right arrow to accept this answer if you find your answer is perfect. thanks.